# Android Node.js Socket.io not connecting in Kitkat 4.4 version after sign apk

Tags: android, socket.io-1.0

I have a Node.js server using socket.io and an android app. I want my app to connect to the server. It works properly in debug mode, but after sign apk socket not connected in Kitkat 4.4.4.

I think it may happen due to proguard rules.
Is there is any way to solve this problem?.

Comment: When you build your APK in release mode, sometimes proguard will print useful console warning. Moreover you need to add to the question your proguard rules file and your dependency list

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem by using an X509TrustManager.

Actually, I am using a @deprecated method of sslSocketFactory - sslSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory);

Instead of i use the updated method -

sslSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory, X509TrustManager trustManager);

X509 certificates may be used to authenticate the remote side of a secure socket. Decisions may be based on trusted certificate authorities, certificate revocation lists, online status checking or other means.